# Creation and God

Tags: theology, creation, genesis-bereishith

What was the purpose of creation? Why did god have the WILL to create a universe? Why create timelines and stories and create a religion? Why not just sit back and party with your angels? Or better yet why need angels at all? Are there references that deal with these questions?

Comment: These might be separate questions, each worthy of their own post (which might already exist), or this is really one question. I can't tell. Can you please clarify?

Comment: More specific than this question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15626/why-did-hashem-create-the-world https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23256/why-was-this-world-created https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/41131/what-is-the-need-for-angels https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16914/why-is-there-so-much-space-and-matter-etc-in-the-universe

Comment: See Aryeh Kaplan's book If You Were G-d.

Comment: VTC, the question is too general to be answered.

Comment: It sounds like the man thrust of this OP is: are there references which deal with these theological questions. @DavidFeigen is this an accurate assessment? If so, maybe edit the post to say "Are there references that deal with the following sort of questions: What was the purpose... Why did G-d..."

Answer (score 2):

The Ramchal answers this in Derech Hashem - in a nutshell

- God is perfect and wants to share his perfection with others
- He created the world in an act of love, to have someone (man) who benefits from His goodness, which is ultimately man's ability to attach himself to the perfect good (God)
- now in order for the gift not to come for free (and be worthless), God created a world of challenges, a body and a soul, a *yetzer hatov* and *yetzer hara* for man to earn credits by dominating his *yetzer hara*.

See Derech Hashem chapter 1 at length, starting [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Derech_Hashem%2C_Part_One%2C_On_the_Purpose_of_Creation.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), (ideally with a very good commentary such as [this one](https://www.feldheim.com/the-elucidated-derech-hashem)) e.g.,

> See that the purpose of creation was to give from His goodness, may He
> be blessed, to another besides Him. [...] His intention, may His name
> be blessed, in the creation that He created was to create someone that
> can benefit from His goodness, may He be blessed, in the manner that
> it is possible for him to benefit from it.

For an excellent simplified presentation of these ideas in modern terms see also [What's the Purpose? Judaism's View on the Meaning of Life](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/1568714947/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_HFW98BJAZ178M9NKVB76) as well as [Aryeh Kaplan Anthology Volume I](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0899068669/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_6ADX4DE6FAN6Q2SCEE54) by R Aryeh Kaplan.